# UploadFromStream or TransferManager.CopyAsync are very slow with large files(400MB or Above) Azure Blob API

Tags: c#, azure, api, model-view-controller, blob

I am facing performance issue with Azure Blob API when uploading large files ex: 400MB or above.

2. When i use TransferManager its working uploading fast in my local application, when i move to azure then again it became slow.
3. I Understand that from file and application are in my local so its uploaded fast. where as azure app is on remote its taking time to upload to azure.
4. How can i read file from File control and convert to Stream  and upload to blob with Azure API?

Used API's are 
`await TransferManager.CopyAsync(sourceBlob, destinationBlob, CopyMethod.ServiceSideSyncCopy, null /* options */, resumeContext);
 cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);`

I appreciate and many thanks in advance for the solution.

Thanks,
Mani

Comment: What does "slow" mean? It helps if we are having timing in milliseconds and the exact number of bytes that test file has. Does the time it takes grows linear with the size of the file?

Comment: Hi Rene,

A 400MB file using transferManager took 80secs in my local and took 5 mins in AZure app.

Thanks,

Comment: If that accounts for network latency then it doesn't seem so bad. Your upload speeds to a datacentre are limited by many factors. What is the timing for 200, 100, 50 and 1MB files?

Comment: 1 to 10 mb files are uploading from API within 5secs which is fine.
50Mb file took 1 minute form API, 15 secs throught azure exlorer.
I want to meet azure explorer upload speed nearer.

Comment: I haven't looked into Azure Explorer but I assume they could compress the stream first before sending it and then decompress at the server side before actually storing it as is. It seems unlikely they use the same API and the same networkpath.